# Text View and Image view not showing in android studio layout when I use a custom toolbar with its theme set using the materials library

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I made an android activity in which I had a custom toolbar (which had theme set to one of the themes of the material library) .However , I am facing serious issues as when I try to add an image view and a text view to my layout , I cannot see them in my layout and on running the app,the app crashes . Can someone recommend a solution to this problem?

Here is the snapshot of my code along with the layout
Here is the XML code

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".AddHappyPlace">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarAdd"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/newColorPrimaryDark"
            android:theme="@style/CustomNoActionBarTheme"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
              android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/etTitle"
              android:hint="Title" android:textColorHint="#d3d3d3"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/etDetails"
                    android:hint="Details"
                    android:textColorHint="#d3d3d3"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/etLocation"
                            android:hint="Location" android:textColorHint="#d3d3d3"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                            android:id="@+id/etDate"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:hint="Date"
                            android:textColorHint="#d3d3d3" />
                </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:id="@+id/imgView"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"/>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvAddImage"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:textSize="25sp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:text="ADD IMAGE"
                    android:layout_height="250dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Here is what the layout is showing
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngXd3.png)

Comment: Please add an image of the "expected output"

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are hosting multiple child inside scrollview,
Scrollview can host only single child. Please check below code for reference

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".AddHappyPlace">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbarAdd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/newColorPrimaryDark"
        android:theme="@style/CustomNoActionBarTheme"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/etTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Title"
            android:textColorHint="#d3d3d3" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/etDetails"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Details"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorHint="#d3d3d3" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/etLocation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Location"
            android:textColorHint="#d3d3d3" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/etDate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Date"
            android:textColorHint="#d3d3d3" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAddImage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="ADD IMAGE"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```